# Why does MatPlotLib shows loglog plots not like it is planned?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My goal is to save an image like this

[image: graphs 1]

But when my code is running it saves it like this

[image: graphs 2]

The code I am using

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.grid(True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
plt.grid(True)
plt.loglog(X, ch1_fft.mean, 'b-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch1_fft.max, 'y--', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch1_max.mean, 'k-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch1_max.max, 'c--', linewidth = 2)
plt.legend([r'Ch1 $FFT_{mean}$', r'Ch1 $FFT_{max}$', r'Ch1 $Max_{mean}$', r'Ch1 $Max_{max}$'])
plt.xticks(ticks= X, labels=xLabels)

ax2 = plt.subplot(312)
plt.grid(True)
plt.loglog(X, ch2_fft.mean, 'b-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch2_fft.max, 'y--', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch2_max.mean, 'k-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch2_max.max, 'c--', linewidth = 2)
plt.legend([r'Ch2 $FFT_{mean}$', r'Ch2 $FFT_{max}$', r'Ch2 $Max_{mean}$', r'Ch2 $Max_{max}$'])
plt.xticks(ticks= X, labels=xLabels)

ax3 = plt.subplot(313)
plt.grid(True)
plt.loglog(X, ch3_fft.mean, 'b-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch3_fft.max, 'y--', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch3_max.mean, 'k-', linewidth = 2)
plt.loglog(X, ch3_max.max, 'c--', linewidth = 2)
plt.legend([r'Ch3 $FFT_{mean}$', r'Ch3 $FFT_{max}$', r'Ch3 $Max_{mean}$', r'Ch3 $Max_{max}$'])
plt.xticks(ticks= X, labels=xLabels)

manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.window.showMaximized()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

This problem may be solved if I do anything on any subplot first (like move it or zoom in), then I press the "Home" button. Also I tried adding `plt.pause(5)`, so it probably could "redraw" plots properly, but that did not help either.

This task is a part of automatic data processing, where it might be from 12 to whatever amount of this plots.

**Update**

Big thanks to @fdireito, the problem was found in `plt.xticks`. To solve this problem you can either delete this lines or add `plt.xlim` and it will work properly

Comment: What matplotlib version are you using? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: @jared my current matplotlib version is 3.7.1

Comment: Is the saved plot also messed up or does that look normal?

Comment: @jared It is also messed up. Actually, it doesn't matter if I save plot or it just shows up until i close GUI window - it is always messed up

Comment: What happens without the xticks lines?

Comment: @fdireito just checked - it works properly without plt.xticks. Also, it will work properly if add plt.xlim when plt.xticks is used. Thank you very much!